# How to find which function opened the socket?

Tags: c++, c, linux, debugging, sockets

I have one process running 24*7 in a system. Recenly it has been reported that this process is opening too many sockets exhausting its max limit.

```
root@typhoon-base-unit0:/root> lsof -p 681 | grep -i sock | wc -l
1018
root@typhoon-base-unit0:/root>
```

Strace revealed that its opening/closing a socket each iteration but suddenly there are many sockets opened by the process which are not closed correctly.

```
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 485
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 486
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 487
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 488
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 489
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 490
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 491
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 492
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 493
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 494
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 495
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 496
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 497
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 498
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 499
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 500
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 501
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 502
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 503
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 504
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 505
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 506
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 507
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 508
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 509
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 510
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 511
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 512
socket(0x1e /* PF_??? */, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0) = 513
close(513)                              = 0
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 513
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 514
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 515
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 516
socket(0x1e /* PF_??? */, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0) = 517
close(517)                              = 0
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 517
socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, 11)      = 518
```

My question how can i find out which function of that running process has created this PF_NETLINK socket? The code is too big to follow all possible paths manually. Is there any tool that can tell me which function created these PF_NETLINK sockets?

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: The [`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) command is a good command to search a large number of files quickly. And if you're in an IDE then that most likely have a "Search all files" functionality as well.

Comment: By the way, I hope you're not logged in as `root` too often? That's a pretty big security hole. Instead consider running the programs that really needs it using [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Comment: Ehr, not hole, but it's a big security risk.

Comment: There is no tool that can tell you after-the-fact. You might have luck with gdb – set a tracepoint on the socket syscall and tell gdb to print a backtrace and continue whenever it hits the tracepoint.

Comment: @thejb, Yes there is: use strace+. It's absolutely fantastic, basically a normal strace *but with backtraces*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it under a debugger, and set a breakpoint in `socket()`. When the breakpoint hits, do a stack trace.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. GDB printed the traceback when socket() was called. The traceback was very long but fortunately could figure out what was going wrong. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use strace+ with normal strace option to track socket() system call.
It should give you a stack trace to the line of source code that made the call.
Steps to use it are here :
http://code.google.com/p/strace-plus/

Comment: Strace+ really seems great. But unfortunately, My system doesn't have this tool so couldn't use it. My bad. But many thanks as i wasn't aware of this tool at all.

Comment: strace+ does not come pre-packaged. You can install it in 4 steps.Just follow the procedure in the link above.